# Change default depth in R collapsibletree package

Tags: r, parent-child, hierarchical-data, collapsibletree-r

I have some simple hierarchical data (parent-child hierarchy) that I would like to visualize in R. I am currently using the R package "collapsibletree" but have not found a way to change the default depth to show the tree with, perhaps, 3 levels expanded. I know I can either show the full tree (collapsed = FALSE) or have it display fully collapsed (collapsed = TRUE) but have not found a way to specify the default depth. Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

Sample data and code included below.

dput:

```
  structure(list(ParentNode = c(NA, "President", "President", "CFO", 
"COO", "Operations SVP", "FP&A SVP", "FP&A VP", "FP&A Senior Analyst"
), Node = c("President", "COO", "CFO", "FP&A SVP", "Operations SVP", 
"Operations VP", "FP&A VP", "FP&A Senior Analyst", "FP&A Associate"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

| Node | ParentNode | ID | ParentID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| President |  | 1 |  |
| COO | President | 2 | 1 |
| CFO | President | 3 | 1 |
| Accounting SVP | CFO | 4 | 3 |
| FP&A SVP | CFO | 5 | 3 |
| FP&A VP | FP&A SVP | 6 | 5 |
| Senior Analyst | FP&A VP | 7 | 6 |
| Senior Associate | FP&A VP | 8 | 6 |
| Associate | Senior Associate | 9 | 8 |
| Intern | Associate | 10 | 9 |

[image]

```
> library(collapsibleTree)
> Data1 <- read.csv(".....csv", na.strings ='', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> Data2 <- Data1[, c(2,1)]
> collapsibleTreeNetwork(Data2, collapsed = TRUE, inputId = 'node')
```

Comment: Hi ADT. There is no sample data. There's only a picture of your data, which is far less useful than _reproducible_ data in text format. Obviously, we can't copy-paste the image into our consoles to reproduce your data. Please [edit] your question to include the output of `dput(Data1)`

Comment: thanks @AllanCameron, just added data that can be referenced

Comment: are you not able to apply the solution below to this data? If not, could you _please_ copy-paste the output of `dput(Data1)` into your question to allow a reproducible result?

Comment: @AllanCameron I've added dput ouput in the body of the original query. I've been trying to implement a variation of  collapsed = c(rep(FALSE, 3), rep(TRUE, 55)) as you noted previously but am struggling to get it to work. Is this code applicable, noting that I am using "collapsibletreenetwork" rather than "collapsibletree"? Thanks for all your prior time assisting with this - I appreciate the help (I'm obviously quite rusty at the moment).

Answer (score 2):

We don't have any reproducible data, so let's use the built-in dataset `warpbreaks`, as used in the `collapsibleTree` help file.

By default, all nodes except the root node are collapsed:

```r
library(collapsibleTree)

collapsibleTree(df = warpbreaks, 
                hierarchy = c("wool", "tension", "breaks"))
```

[image]

If we set `collapsed = FALSE` then all nodes are expanded:

```r
collapsibleTree(df = warpbreaks, 
                hierarchy = c("wool", "tension", "breaks"),
                collapsed = FALSE)
```

[image]

If you want a different starting arrangement, then according to the help file, the `collapsed` argument can be used as follows:

> For `data.frame` input, can also be a vector of logical values the same length as the number of nodes. Follows the same logic as the fill vector.

The entry for `fill` tells us:

> By default, vector should be ordered by level, such that the root color is described first, then all the children's colors, and then all the grandchildren's colors

So we want to show the next level of the tree after the default value, we need `collapsed` to be a vector of 3 `FALSE` followed by 55 `TRUE`.

In general, we can work out the correct nodes to collapse by passing this function:

```r
collapse_depth <- function(depth = 0) {
  args <- as.list(sys.call(1))[-1]
  cols <- eval(args$hierarchy)
  data <- eval(args$df)
  if(length(cols) < depth) depth <- length(cols)
  if(depth <= 1) return(TRUE)
  depth <- round(depth)
  n_nodes <- sum(unlist(lapply(seq_along(cols), function(i) {
    length(levels(factor(do.call("paste", data[unlist(cols[seq(i)])]))))
    }))) + 1
  n_expand <- sum(unlist(lapply(seq(depth - 1), function(i) {
  length(levels(factor(do.call("paste", data[unlist(cols[seq(i)])]))))
  }))) + 1
  return(c(rep(FALSE, n_expand), rep(TRUE, n_nodes - n_expand)))
}
```

This allows

```r
collapsibleTree(df = warpbreaks, 
                hierarchy = c("wool", "tension", "breaks"),
                collapsed = collapse_depth(2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @allencameron. What is the significance of 55?

Comment: There  are 58 nodes. The first 3 are expanded. The other 55 are collapsed

Comment: @allencameron Another quick question. Re. the warpbreaks data, how do you determine the number of nodes? There are 54 rows in the dataframe - would this not be the number of nodes? Thanks again for your patience.


> nrow(warpbreaks)
[1] 54

Comment: @asdfjkl no, there is not one node for each row of the data frame. There is one root node, then one node for each unique value of `wool` (2), one node for each unique combination of `wool` and `tension` (6), and one node for each unique combination of `wool`, `tension` and `breaks` (49). I'll add a function to my answer that automates this.